# passing commandline argument

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a script which in turn runs some other code and I need to check some conditions in latter code before it gets executed! So i thought of using command line arguments and I don't have better knowledge on OOP concepts to write classes which was recommended in most of the answers given for similar questions in stack overflow.
can I pass arguments like this

```
subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'Cnt1', 'argument1', 'argument2'])
```

If I can, how to read the arguments in the latter code?
I tried to print

```
print sys.executable
print Cnt1
```

its showing error for print Cnt1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed run `python` using the `subprocess` module, and pass arguments to that. In essence you'd be running a completely new program; this is not the same as calling a function. *Usually* there is no need to go to such drastic lengths though.

If you do run a separate python script, you need to parse the arguments passed from [`sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv). The [`argparse` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) makes that easier but is not required if all you do is pass a list of arguments.

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

Answer (score 1):

you have specified `'Cnt1'` as a string in subprocess call

and `print Cnt1` will produce an error since `Cnt1` is not a variable

you syntax should be `subprocess.call([sys.executable, Cnt1, argument1, argument2])`

assuming you have required values in Cnt1, argument1 and argument2 variables